# plot only those histograms with n number of counts

Tags: ggplot2

My data looks like [this](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZsOYWkZj1OcfzC4OqHW0QvYQNDITpCUEzYV). With this code I get lots of histograms for all my different `Space.Groups`.

```
massaged <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dummy.tsv")
library(tidyverse)
df <- na.omit(massaged)
ggplot() + 
geom_histogram(data = df, mapping = aes(x = pH.Value)) + 
facet_grid(. ~ Space.Group)
```

As you can see, most of my histograms contain a few total number of counts.
[image]

I am interested in only those histograms with a total number of counts greater than 100. For this particular plot I was trying to do something like

```
ggplot(data = filter(df, Uniprot.Recommended.Name == "Beta-2-microglobulin", Space.Group == %in% c("P 1 21 1", "P 1", "P 21 21 21", "C 1 2 1"))) +
 geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = pH.Value)) +
 facet_grid(. ~ Space.Group)
```

Which by the way it does not work and is not very automatic because I have to make the first plot and then check by hand which `Space.Groups` are the interesting ones.
My question: Is it possible to tell ggplot2 to only plot those histograms with a total number of counts greater than a number (100, in this case).

Comment: Filter the data beforehand with code like `df %>% group_by(Space.Group)%>% filter(n() > 100) %>% ggplot(...)`. Your code does not work because of `== %in%` which should be `%in%`

Comment: I think your approach does not work, because each `Uniprot.Recommended.Name` can be crystallized in different `Space.Groups` and with a different `pH.Value`. The suggested edit to my code works, but it is way more work...  I have to create the plots, then annotating the interesting `Space.Groups` and doing the new plot again.

Comment: So each `Uniprot.Recommended.Name` can be subsetted further by `pH.Value` and `Space.Group`?  Seems the filtering suggestion beforehand is the way to go.  You can use `group_by()` with more than one term to create sub-sets and sub-subsets, etc, then filter where `n() > 100`.  So something like this:  `df %>% group_by(Uniprot.Recommended.Name, Space.Groups, pH.Value) %>% dplyr::filter(n() > 100) %>% ggplot(...)`.  What about that?  You may want to do the filter separately and have a look at the groups first to make sure that's working, then you can pipe it together via `%>%`.

Comment: It works. It is also good to get a table of the data frame grouped by variables.